# How to handle dispatching of touch events with FireMonkey?

Tags: android, firemonkey, c++builder

How can I handle the dispatching of touch events with FireMonkey ?

I need to control the dispatching of touch events to cancel the dispatching if a click callback of a component is already processing. So that only one click callback can be registered/executed at a time.

Some hurried users often click multiple times and this can lead to multiple bugs that would not occur otherly.

The solution used in my project to mitigate this is `TComponent->enabled = false; ... TComponent->enabled = true;` but isn't always effective, implies to be done on every clickable component and doesn't prevent from clicking other components.

I've found some links on the subject but the 1st doesn't seem to use FireMonkey and the second is only about gestures.

> https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781783989645/8/ch08lvl1sec93/time-for-action--handling-touch-events
>
> http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Gestures_in_FireMonkey

The TTouchManager class doesn't seem to provide any useful control on this either :

> http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Types.TTouchManager

Comment: I don't think you should manage the touch events. It should be the click handlers that just refuse to execute meaningful code if another copy of them is running (possibly in a separate thread). You can do this with a try finally block and a boolean guard variable.

Comment: I've already thought of that, but doesn't this would need to be done for every click callback function ? This seems to be very time consuming for an unmaintainable code.

Comment: Any solution you choose will require you to implement in all UI event handlers. Another one some developers use is to overlay a transparent or semitransparent panel over the UI when the event handlers are running... de facto deactivating the UI. A try finally is also required in this case... so the code is very similar.